# Populate a second select-box with contents from SQL depending on the selection in the first (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, select

I know this topic has been discussed to death before and I apologize to cause any inconvenience. I don't want to offend anyone. I just couldn't apply any of the proposed solution strategies on my code.

Here is what I have: A MySQL-DB on a webserver, which is up and running. This DB contains a table called worldcities, which has Countries, Cities and their Lat/Lon values stored.

I have a PHP-file on my server which successfully establishes a connection and reads out all the Countries and populates a first select box. My second select box should contain all the Cities based on the Country selection in the first box. My code currently contains a placeholder SQL query.

I understand PHP is a serverside technology, that needs assistance in order to interact with user input on the clientside. I just don't get how to solve my problem here.

Could someone be so kind to help/guide me to solve my issue? It would mean the world to me. Thank you very much in advance.

Code:

```
<?php
$dbhost     = "xxx";
$dbname     = "xxx";
$dbtable    = "xxx";
$dbuser     = "xxx";
$dbpass     = "xxx";

try{
    $pdo = new PDO( "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8", "$dbuser", "$dbpass" );
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch( PDOException $e ){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$query_country_start = $pdo->query( "SELECT Country FROM $dbtable GROUP BY Country" );
$query_city_start = $pdo->query( "SELECT City FROM $dbtable ORDER BY City" );
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Select Country and City</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Select Country and City</h1>
<div id="cities">

<p>Start Country</p>
<?php
    echo '<select name="country_start">';
    while ($row = $query_country_start->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Country'].'">'.$row['Country'].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select><br><br>';
?>

<p>Start City</p>
<?php
    echo '<select name="city_start">';
    while ($row = $query_city_start->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['City'].'">'.$row['City'].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
?>
</div>

<script>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How many valid permutations are there ? Dozens? Thousands?

Comment: @Strawberry: Yeah, lots. There are around 190 Countries and 10.500 Cities stored in the dbtable.

Answer (score 0):

Populating the second box is a lot harder. This is because you are now wanting to populate a box based on a user selection.

Here are the basic components -

1. Use a Javascript event handler to fire when the first select box is updated.
2. Fire an AJAX call back to the web server to invoke a PHP method.
3. Method will query the database to get you a list of cities which is filtered by the selected country. The results are echoed back to the front end.
4. Javascript reads the results in and updates the cities select box.

There's a lot of concepts to wrap your head around here, but there are also a lot of tutorials that you can follow and draw inspiration from.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMmXzjJWlnU

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Sadly I'm not a coder, so I have a really hard time understanding the technologies you were referencing. :(